# Ubuntu Core not booting in Raspberry pi 4

Tags: boot, raspberrypi, sd-card, ubuntu-core, nextcloud

I've been running Ubuntu Core (I guess 18)  in a Rpi 4 4Gb like charm for a while. The only use was a nextcloud server. About a week ago the system stopped running and now it doesn't boot. I only get a rainbow screen. System is in a sd card.

I've tried to run the recovery by pressing "1" in a keyboard (usb plugged) without success, I only get the rainbow screen

I've tried to run a different OS in a different sd card, and the Rpi seems ok

The sd card is readable in another PC, so maybe there's a file corrupted, but definitively not the complete sd card

As system doesn't boot, I don't know what to do, or how to obtain more info to look for a solution.

Comment: Core 16 has reached end of life and is not supported on this site if that is the product you are asking about.

Comment: Sorry, core 18. This is what I have installed: https://ubuntu.com/appliance/nextcloud

Comment: Interesting. My Ubuntu Core 18 stopped running about a week ago as well although I seem to get further - I get to the Ubuntu Core logo and it stops at that point.  I have also done both your tests - Rpi works fine on another card and the SD card is readable on other computers.

Comment: Very interesting. My Nextcloud Ubuntu Appliance too is experiencing the same problem. I too get to the Ubuntu Core logo and it stops there. Raspberry Pi 4 works fine too on another Ubuntu Desktop SD card.

Comment: Well, I'm starting from scratch... I hope it desn't happen again

Comment: I made a fresh installation,made everything run and while it was syncing the files something happened with the SD, even when it looks ok in a PC, so I'm done with it :( I've ordered a minipc where I'll install Ubunti Server or desktop and I'll use the Raspi for another project :(